# Can PIL or Pillow get the Directory 0 Offset in a TIFF File?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I want to get the Directory offset value from a TIFF Image File Directory. PIL/Pillow and other packages can get me the tiff tags, but this value isn't from the tiff tags, but rather from the IFD header.

This is for a project on Ubuntu using Python 3.7. I just want to get the IFD offset value.

From a prompt, I'd just do this:

```
tiffdump 1.tif
1.tif:
Magic: 0x4949 <little-endian> Version: 0x2a <ClassicTIFF>
Directory 0: offset 10216 (0x27e8) next 12902 (0x3266)
SubFileType (254) LONG (4) 1<0>
ImageWidth (256) SHORT (3) 1<1187>
ImageLength (257) SHORT (3) 1<552>
.
.
.
```

That 10216 value is what I'm after.

PIL/Pillow (from my understanding) use libtiff to do something similar to get the tiff tags. But this value is not in the tiff tags. For some files, the STripBytecounts + the StripOffsets gives me the correct IFD offset, but this is not deterministic:

```
# get offset for x.tif
im = Image.open(final_dataset + str(x) + ".tif")
tag_dict = im.tag_v2
StripByteCounts = (tag_dict.get(279))
StripOffsets = (tag_dict.get(273))
tiff_directory_offset = (StripByteCounts[0] + StripOffsets[0])
```

I suspect I'm missing something very simple in order to get the value I want. any ideas?

Comment: Try `im.tag_v2.offset`

Comment: That did it, thank you. I'm going to dive back into the documentation and try to find that now. Is it worth making this an answer so I can flag it as correct?